# Parameters for Support Vector Regression using LibSVM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am trying to use LibSVM for regression. I am trying to detect faces (10 classes of different faces). I labeled 1-10 as face class and 11 is for non face. I want to develop a script usig LibSVM which will give me a continuous score between 0-1 if the test image falls to any of the 10 face class, otherwise it will give me -1 (non-face). From this score, I can be able to predict my calss. If the test image is matched with 1st class, the score should be around .1. Similarly if the test image is matched with class 10, the score should be around 1 (any continuous value close to 1). I am trying to use SVR using LibSVM to solve this problem. I can easily get the predicted class through classification. But I want a continuous score value which I can get through regression. Now, I was looking in the net for the function or parameters in function for SVR using LibSVM, but I couldn't find anything. Can anybody please help me in this regard?

Comment: This is still not really regression. Predicting values between 0 and 1 can be done with Platt scaling, which turns an SVM into a probability model.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a regression problem. Solving it through regression will not yield good results.

You are dealing with a multiclass classification problem. The best way to approach this is to construct 10 one-vs-all classifiers with probabilistic output. To get probabilistic output (e.g. in the interval [0,1]), you can train and predict with the `-b 1` option for C-SVC (`-s 0`).

If any of the 10 classifiers yields a sufficiently large probability for its positive class, you use that probability (which is close to 1). If none of the 10 classifiers yield a positive label with high enough confidence you can default to -1.

So in short: make a multiclass classifier containing one-vs-all classifiers with probabilistic output. Subsequently post-process the predictions as I described, using a probability threshold of your choice (for example 0.7).

Comment: Thanks Marc. I have tried that one. But I was confused that how I can get a certain positive value (between 0.0 and 1.0) for a certain class. For example, I want an ideal score of 0.1 if the image is close enough to class 1, 0.2 if the test image is close enough to class 2, 0.3 if the test image is close enough to class 3 and so on (1.o if the test image is close enough to class 10). Also the score can not be discrete, menaing it can have a value 6.56 (in which case I will asume that it is close enoungh to class 7.

Comment: @user2433638: you can do this using 2 steps: (1) find the classifier with highest probability for its positive class, lets say it's class k with probability prob(k) (2) value = k-1+prob(k). If the maximum probability you find is below a threshold you specify, yield -1.

Comment: ). Now, I can get the score using parameter '-b 1' and take the highest probability score to classify (I have already done this), but then different class will have the same probability values (meaning that with probability score 8.81, class 1 or class 10 or class 5 can be classified in diffrent execution). In stead, I want that with score 8.81, I will know that the test image is classified as class 9."

Comment: When you choose to output probabilities in LIBSVM, you will still obtain the predicted class label as well. You can then post-process the resulting label+probability into the form you want.

Comment: value = k-1+prob(k), from this equation, say I have a probability score of .35 and k is 7. Now the above equation will give me answer 6.35 (or .635). But in that case, I have to pick class 6 (not 7) as .635 is closer to .6 than .7.

Comment: If I can use value = k/10-(0.5)+prob(k), then I think I can get a score what I want. But then a probablity score of (.5) would be the perfect match scenario although in reality it is not the case.

Comment: That is why I said to yield -1 if the maximum probability is below a certain threshold (which must be atleast 0.5). The equation I suggested will work as described if you set an appropriate threshold.

Comment: Thanks Marc for all your suggestions. Now in another view, if say I want to do just regression (for some time, I want to forget about my classification). Say, I want regression score is like that -

Comment: continued....If I have an exact match, I will output 1. If I have not exact match, but my test face is matches with faces of another class. In these cases, I will output a score between 0.1-0.99. If my test faces does not match with any of the face class, then I have a score of -1. Now is this can be solved via epsilon - SVR in LibSVM? Any suggestion is welcome. Also closer to 1.0 means more similar to exact match, closer to -1.0 means less similarity. In one word, I want to have a continuous score between 0.1 - 1.0 for match and -1.0 for non-match.